# Como hacer que la búsqueda `MATCH() AGAINST()` ignore los tildes o acentos?

Tags: mysql, buscador, tildes

Tengo una tabla llamada `productos` la cual tiene una columna tipo `varchar` llamada `nombre` codificada en `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Estoy tratando de hacer una solicitud de búsqueda para filtrar productos por su nombre usando la sentencia `MATCH() AGAINST()`. Esta es mi solicitud:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM productos
WHERE MATCH(nombre) AGAINST('*palabra_a_buscar*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Funciona bastante bien para cadenas de caracteres que no tienen caracteres especiales como tildes, sin embargo, dentro de mi base de datos tengo productos que llevan tilde, y si la persona quiere buscar un producto llamado `"Colágeno"`, y escribe en el buscador la palabra `"Colageno"`, la solicitud mysql no devolverá el producto.

Así que intenté lo que una persona respondió en [esta respuesta de Stack overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161312/13615635), pero no tuve éxito.

> ```sql
> SELECT *
> FROM productos
> WHERE MATCH(CONVERT(BINARY(nombre) USING utf8)) AGAINST('*Colageno*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
> ```

Obtuve un error de sintaxis:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONVERT(BINARY(name) USING utf8)) AGAINST('*Colageno*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)' at line 3

Dentro de mi base de datos tengo solo caracteres especiales con tilde -> `á, é, í, ó, ú`.

Si alguien me puede ayudar o guiar sobre lo que debo hacer lo agradecería mucho! Llevo desde ayer atascado con esto.

Comment: ¿Puedes aún [cambiar el enconding](https://superuser.com/a/978207) de esa base de datos, por ejemplo a `utf8mb4_general_ci`, o al menos a `utf8_general_ci`? Debido a generalmente los lenguajes trabajan con UTF8 ya no habría que estar haciendo conversiones de encondings al acceder a la BD. Al menos en UTF8 ignora las tildes o ñ, y no importa si buscas con o sin ellas, trae los mismos resultados.

Comment: @aeportugal soy un poco nuevo con esto de los encoding en mysql. Si yo cambio el encoding a `utf8_general_ci`, eso actualizaría todos los tildes por la letra sin tilde en la columna? o dejaría la columna como está y al momento de buscar ignoraría las tildes?

Comment: Ojo con los cambios de encoding porque puedes corromper todos los datos... si lo haces lo suyo es exportar toda la tabla a un fichero de texto, convertir ese fichero al nuevo encoding, cambiar todas las collations en el fichero, y luego importarla de nuevo como nueva, y eso siempre teniendo copia de seguridad de la anterior por si acaso hay que tirar atras

Comment: Podrias probar con esta consulta, sin cambiar nada, a ver si cuela:  `SELECT *
FROM productos
WHERE MATCH(nombre COLLATE utf8_bin) AGAINST('*palabra_a_buscar*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` ... aunque ese collate distingue mayúsculas y minúsculas, tan solo prueba a ver si da error, y si no lo da le cambias el collate por otro como `utf8mb4` o `utf8` a secas

Comment: @masterguru Probé con los 3 tipos de collate pero me tira error de sintaxis en la parte de `COLLATE utf8) AGAINST('*colageno*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`. Ahora voy a intentar hacer el cambio de encoding con una copia de seguridad por si me la mando ;). Luego actualizo la pregunta con los resultados, gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Ojo de nuevo con el cambio de encoding, pues no solo afectará a tu tabla, sino a los scripts que accedan a ella como hasta ahora lo estaban haciendo, pues no tendran en cuenta este cambio y si alguno inserta o actualiza datos lo hara seguramente con el anterior encoding que hasta ahora funcionaba... y lo mismo al mostrarlos mediante scripts.. no es un cambio liviano

Comment: Por defecto, estas búsquedas no diferencian entre caracteres normales y sus correspondientes con diacríticos; el problema podría ser la forma en que guardas esos caracteres, tal vez en lugar de `colágeno` en la tabla se está guardando `col&aacute;geno` y, por supuesto, no va a aparecer en resultados.

Comment: @Triby, Sí, de hecho la palabra se guarda así `COLÃ<0x81>GENO`. Sin embargo, si yo manualmente modifico la celda desde la base de datos para poner el tilde `COLÁGENO`, la tabla se corrompe y no ejecuta ninguna solicitud bien. También hice la prueba del cambio de encoding, pero sucedió lo mismo que acabo de describir. Para solucionarlo tal vez debería modificar la string de búsqueda para que los tildes se pongan en el formato que guarda la base de datos, es eso buena idea o hay algo mejor?

Comment: Entonces tiene problemas generales de codificación y, seguramente, deberías migrar para poder guardar esos caracteres correctamente y evitar este problema... entre muchos otros.

Comment: @AlexSp3 ¿Estás en linux?  Si es así al exportar la tabla con el phpmyadmin ejecuta un `file archivo.sql` para ver que codificación usa.

Comment: @masterguru Estoy en windows, pero ejecuté `show variables like "character_set_database"` que parece ser equivalente y como resultado me dio `latin1`.

Comment: No es lo mismo, pero bueno... suponiendo que lo fuera, una vez exportado ¿como  has convertido el archivo exportado a utf8 en windows antes de importarlo?  ¿Y le has cambiado todos los latin1 por utf8mb4 que tenia dentro?  ¿Es muy grande el archivo exportado?

Comment: @masterguru solo he exportado la tabla, no la base de datos entera. La tabla pesa 45 kb en formato sql, no es muy grande. Probé cambiar el encoding de tabla usando (esto)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116205/13615635], pero sin cambios, seguía sin reconocer los tildes, así que lo siguiente que hice fue modificar manualmente en la tabla `COLÃ<0x81>GENO` por `COLÁGENO`, y luego de eso la tabla se corrompe y no puedo ejecutar instrucciones. (Cabe aclarar que si no hago el cambio de encoding, pero si modifique la tilde manualmente la tabla se corrompe igual)

Comment: Luego intenté hacer el cambio de encoding cambiando en el archivo de la tabla exportado `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4`, pero sucedió lo mismo que puse en el comentario anterior

Comment: mmm... a ver, diria que no lo has hecho bien. Se exporta la tabla a un archvo de texto sql, luego se cambia el encoding del archivo mediante una conversión de caracteres con algun editor lo soporte, como el sublime o notepad++ en windows (lo siento, no conozco apenas editores para windows), **después** cambia eso del DEFAULT CHARSET, y luego importas la tabla de nuevo.  Por cierto, que usas?  mysql o mariadb?  Fíjate si en la exportación si la estructura de la tabla pone el collate tambien en cada campo tambien pues lo tendras que cambiar igual (busca latin por ahi)...

Comment: Ops, veo que ya lo has solucionado, perdon, si ya está entonces nada, me alegro! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solucionado!

Luego de la discusión en los comentarios me di cuenta que el error no radicaba en la instrucción `MATCH() AGAINST()`, ya que este por default no distingue diacríticos.

Entonces el problema tenía que ver con como los diacríticos se guardabn en MySQL, en mi caso, se guardaban así `COLÁGENO` -> `COLÃ<0x81>GENO`. Por lo tanto, había que averiguar como guardar las tildes correctamente sin corromper la tabla.

#### Encodings

Probé haciendo cambios de encoding ejecutando en phpmyadmin la instrucción:

```sql
ALTER TABLE productos CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Sin embargo no hubo cambios en el funcionamiento.

Luego, probé cambiar el encoding en el archivo de la tabla exportado cambiando `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1` por `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4`, pero tampoco obtuve cambios en los resultados.

#### Modificar las tildes manualmente

Mi otro intento fue, una vez realizado el cambio de encoding, modificar manualmente las celdas que tenían caracteres como `Ã<0x81>` por su correspondiente caracter con tilde `Á`. Pero lamentablemente, esto parecía corromper las consultas a la tabla (todavía podía acceder a las otras tablas normalmente).

Entonces pensé en lo que masterguru dijo en los comentarios sobre que los cambios de encoding alteran la forma en la que los scripts se conectan a la tabla y, al parecer, cuando modificaba manualmente un caracter para poner la tilde, los scripts seguían accediendo a la tabla con la codificación anterior.

#### Solución

Los scripts estaban en PHP así que tuve que buscar la solución en ese lenguaje.

Encontré [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780302/13615635) en SO inglés donde decía como guardar tildes en la base de datos de manera correcta. Para ello, había que escribir...

```php
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
```

...esto luego de la conexión a la base de datos. Por último, tuve que cambiar los caracteres raros en mi base de datos por su correspondiente caracter con tilde para que el `MATCH AGAINST` funcione, y listo!

---

Muchas gracias a masterguru, Triby y aeportugal por la ayuda proporcionada en los comentarios!